# Proving that a function $G: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is continuous.

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions, dual-spaces

$(X, ||\cdot||)$ is a normed vector space, and $l_0, l_1, ..., l_n$ are linear operators in $X^*$. And $G$ is defined like this. $G:X\rightarrow R^{n+1}: x\rightarrow (l_0(x), l_1(x), ..., l_n(x))$. How do I prove that G is continuous?
I've already proven that $G$ is linear but for continuity I'm a little lost. I'm trying by proving that a $L\geq 0$ exist such that $||G(x)|| \leq L\cdot||x||$, and applying that to each $l_i(x)$ because for each one, a different $L$ exits, given that they are continuous. So I thought that $||G(x)||$ could be bounded by the sum of all the different $L_i$ times $||x||$. Is that correct?
All this cosidering the euclidian norm for $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: It's just $\Vert G(x) \Vert^2 = \sum_{j=0}^n \vert l_j(x) \vert^2 \leq \sum_{j=0}^n L_j ^2\Vert x \Vert^2 = L^2 \Vert x \Vert^2$ for all $x\in X$, where $L=\sqrt{\sum_{j=0}^n L_j^2}$, so the norm is not just the sum of the respective norms, but again the euclidian norm.

Comment: @stange thank you!! I got it now. I had what you said in mind but I didn't really know how to connect everything and formalize it. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $X^*$ is the *continuous* dual space. If that's the case, then it's a basic property of the product topology that a map $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is continuous iff its projection onto each factor is continuous. In other words, each of the maps $l_i : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, so $G$ is continuous.